# Getting error in system debug

Tags: apex, debug

while executing this code,am getting this error:
 Method does not exist or incorrect signature: `void substring(Integer, Integer)` from the type `List<MVImportBatch__c>`

code:

```
 List<MVImportBatch__c> record = new List<MVImportBatch__c>();
record =[SELECT Id FROM MVImportBatch__c limit 1];
Integer cid;
cid= record.substring(0,3);
system.debug('cid:'+cid);
```

error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void substring(Integer, Integer) from the type List

Answer (score 1):

`substring()` is of `String` type and not of `List` type. Replace line 4 with this:

```
   String cid= String.valueOf(record.Id).substring(0,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to get first 3 symbols of record id?

```
MVImportBatch__c record = [
    select Id 
    from MVImportBatch__c
    limit 1
];
String cid = String.valueOf(record.Id).substring(0,3);
System.debug('cid:'+cid);
```